# mirror not working with armature handles

Tags: rigging, mirror

i'm trying to rig an eagle fr a project and i made a complicated mesh and rig with handles but it can't be mirrored to the other side
[image: good side of rig]
[image: when mirrored]
[image: more views bad]
[image: more views good]

and i can't just apply the rotation or scale because then the handles will not be right they will move and rotate drastically

Comment: this addon helpes https://github.com/scaredyfish/orient_bone_shapes it makes the whole process easier

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/80323)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this addon helpes https://github.com/scaredyfish/orient_bone_shapes it makes the whole process easier.
it makes it so you just select bone and mesh and with a button press it applies the mesh to the bone